# Circular dependency (with inner bean) without duplication - is is possible?

Tags: spring, spring-bean

Take the following configuration:

```
<beans>

    <bean name="myToyota" class="Car">
        <property name="contents">
            <list>
                <bean class="Wheel">
                    <property name="designation"><value>front-left</value></property>
                    <property name="parent"><ref bean="myToyota"/></property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="Wheel">
                    <property name="designation"><value>front-right</value></property>
                    <property name="parent"><ref bean="myToyota"/></property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Is it possible to build this graph without directly referencing `myToyota` from the `Wheel` beans? (Maybe using SpEL).

My concern is that I can not copy-paste the description of the Wheels to an other Car bean without introducing the possibility of broken references (that's me forgetting to adjust the `parent` property by hand).

In other words: is there a way an inner bean can referece it's containing bean without knowing its name?

Comment: Why do you need car and wheel beans? These seem like strange choices for beans.

Comment: @EvanKnowles The car and wheel seemed like good choices for demonstration. The whole problem sprouts from a graph where the contained elements (wheels here) are highly context-sensitive. They choose defaults for unset properties based on the owning object.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do something like the following:

```
public class Car {
private List contents;

public List getContents() {
    return contents;
}

public void setContents(List contents) {
    this.contents = contents;
    for (Iterator iterator = contents.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Wheel object = (Wheel) iterator.next();
        object.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a logical way to remedy the problem. However I would loose the possibility for Wheel to be an `InitializingBean` (setting up defaults based on the Car).

Comment: True, but I don't think there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: An other problem with this solution is that if I have multiple levels of nesting (outer, middle, inner) the innermost class might be bound to the middle one before the middle one is bound to the outer.